# Apache mod_ssl could not be loaded

Tags: apache, ssl

Trying to enable the mod_ssl module on Apache 2.4.25, I get the following error:

httpd: Syntax error on line 129 of /ld01/otsweb/build/apache/httpd24.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: \t0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/local/apache24/modules/mod_ssl.so.\n\t0509-150   Dependent module libssl.so could not be loaded.\n\t0509-022 Cannot load module libssl.so.\n\t0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.\n\t0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/local/apache24/modules/mod_ssl.so.\n\t0509-150   Dependent module /usr/local/apache24/modules/mod_ssl.so could not be loaded.

Line 129 is the LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so line in the httpd.conf file.

I have the same configuration running correctly on another server. That server does not have a libssl.so file on it, yet Apache with SSL is running.

Apache was configured with:  (OpenSSL version is 1.0.2k from openssl.org)

./configure --enable-mods-shared="proxy proxy_http" --enable-auth-digest --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/bin

Has anyone seen this same error?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of OpenSSL 1.0.2l we decided to reinstall Apache from scratch, and everything is working correctly.  A clean install of both seems to have cleared out the problem.